# How are decorators tied to a Flask application instances?

Tags: python, flask

My situation is that I want to ran a Flask application with Apache2 and currently if I do as any Flask tutorial says everything works just fine. My problem is that I don't understand how decorators, namely routers, are tied to a Flask application and none of the tutorials nor the Flask's own documentation is of any use in this regard. I've tried my best to find information regarding how decorators, namely routers, are tied to a Flask application instance but I've come up with nothing. At the moment how everything "just works" and this all seems like witchcraft to me.

Namely, my initial application is something like this:

```
myproject/
    app/
      __init__.py
      routes.py
    myproject.wsgi
```

where `__init__.py` has the following content:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

`routes.py` has the following content:

```
from app import app
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

and `myproject.wsgi` has the following content:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/test')
from app import app as application
```

Now, my application has grown a bit and I would like to implement properly working unit tests for it. My `tests` folder is in the same root directory as the `myproject`.

What is unclear to me is that when I import the `app` from the `myproject` for testing, does it automatically have the functionality assigned to it from the decorators in `routes.py`? If so, why and how does this work? If not, how do I test the functions I assign to an application with decorators? The latter is probably only important when I need to test `POST` requests.

Also, could someone tell me why almost in every Flask tutorial the application, namely the `app` is build in the `__init__.py` file of the project? Wouldn't it be easier to initialize it for example in `app.py` file or something similar?

I've tried my best to find information regarding how decorators, namely routers, are tied to a Flask application instance but I've come up with nothing. At the moment how everything "just works" in Flask seems like witchcraft as in every single

Comment: Regarding the `__init__.py` + tutorials, there's a relevant discussion on this in [issue 2626](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2626).  The advice here seems to encourage **not** having heavy `__init__.py` files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how this could be implemented:

```
class Flask:
    def __init__(self):
        self.routes = {}

    def route(self, uri):
        def wrapper(func):
            self.routes[uri] = func
            return func
        return wrapper

app = Flask()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello"
```

`route` decorator only adds the function `func` to `self.routes` dictionary and returns the same function. So it's just a more fancy way of doing this:

```
def index():
    return "hello"

app.routes['/'] = index
```

And

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello"
```

is just a syntactic sugar for:

```
def index():
    return "hello"

index = app.route('/')(index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the illustration regarding decorators. But I would still like to ask how should I tie my decorator functions to my Flask app instance? As your example Flask class won't (?) have the same content as is in e.g. `app = flask.Flask(__name__)`?

I mean that if I create an app factory function and create an instance of the Flask app via the factory in `routes.py` everything works fine. Yet if I want to test the functions I assign to the app in `routes.py` things get confusing as I'm not sure how to import the specific flask instance which as all the methods tied to it.

Comment: `how to import the specific flask instance` are there many `Flask` instances? Or are you asking how to share the same object in multiple python files?

Comment: The second one, how to share the same object.

My current solution ended up being that I transferred everything under the `routes.py` to an app creation method where I tie the function with decorators. This way I can just create a new instance to have to methods I want.

If you know a better way of doing this please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the [`route` decorator](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/app.py#L1281) (minus its docstring):

```
def route(self, rule, **options):

    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", None)
        self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        return f

    return decorator
```

Notice that the decorator doesn't modify the decorated function at all; it returns `f` as-is. However, it first modifies the `app` *itself* (via the `self` argument) to map the given URL path to the function; this means there are now multiple references to the `index` function: `index itself, plus two held by`app` internally.